# syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: shell-script

```
rhel_major=$(grep -Eoh [0-9]+\.[0-9]+ /etc/{issue,*release} | head -1 | awk -F'.' '{ print $$1 }')
rhel_minor=$(grep -Eoh [0-9]+\.[0-9]+ /etc/{issue,*release} | head -1 | awk -F'.' '{ print $$2 }')
rhel_release_code=$(echo $$(($(rhel_major) << 8 | $(rhel_minor))))
```

For rhel_release_code I get a syntax error

```
rhel_release_code=$(echo $$(("$(rhel_major)" << 8 | $(rhel_minor))))

-bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: command substitution: line 1: `echo $$(("$(rhel_major)" << 8 | $(rhel_minor)))'
```

Any idea why it throws that error?

Comment: Change `echo $$((` to `echo $((` -- the `$$` is being substituted by the process id, before the arithmetic substitution occurs. Also, why the double $ in the awk commands?

Comment: Copy-paste from a Makefile perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` throws an error because it's not valid shell code. (It's also not valid `awk` code.)

Try this

```
rhel_major=$(grep -Eoh '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' /etc/{issue,*release} | awk -F'.' '{ print $1; exit }')
rhel_minor=$(grep -Eoh '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' /etc/{issue,*release} | awk -F'.' '{ print $2; exit }')
rhel_release_code=$((rhel_major << 8 | rhel_minor))
```

If you don't actually want the `$rhel_major` and `$rhel_minor` values you could calculate `$rhel_release` directly in one step using `awk`.